# Overwrite images in a share file

Tags: c#, file, file-upload, system.io.file

I'm making a program that needs to upload files to a share file on a server. I've managed to do this using a third party library.

Is there any way for me to overwrite an image file using C#? I'm able to make uploads, but I'm struggling to find a way to overwrite old image files.

Here's what I tried:

```
FileInfo OldFile = new FileInfo("smb://serverUsername:ServerPassword@serverIP/sharefile/fileToDelete.jpg");
bool FileExists = OldFile.Exists;
Console.WriteLine(FileExists);
```

Even though I know for fact the file on my share drive exists, the Boolean variable came back as false - any reasoning as to why?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the new image has the same name, you can check the existence of the file and delete it before creating the new file.

Note: Make sure the file path is correct (filename along with extension should also be included).

```
if (File.Exists("smb://serverUsername:ServerPassword@serverIP/sharefile/fileToDelete.jpg"))
{
    File.Delete("smb://serverUsername:ServerPassword@serverIP/sharefile/fileToDelete.jpg");
}
```

Comment: How is this different than the example I provided in my question? Aren't they the same?

Comment: I'm not doubting you answer - I just feel as though they are the same

Comment: I just tried this in my code and it.. worked? I'm shocked. Not even sure how that was different than my initial attempt but I appreciate you help. Marking your answer as correct

Comment: Both are the same, But here your requirement is to just check if the file exists so just wanted to be specific.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do you happen to know the difference between the datatype "FileInfo" and a normal string? It works in my code both ways so I was wondering what the benefit of that datatype is

Comment: Here is the use of FileInfo `provides properties and instance methods for the creation, copying, deletion, moving, and opening of files, and aids in the creation of System.IO.FileStream objects`

Answer (score 0):

you may find useful the function "replace", also this will allow to do a backup for the file (if you want)

```
string backup = destination + ".bak";
File.Delete(backup);
File.Replace(source, destination, backup, true);
```

You can play a little with that.

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.replace?view=netcore-3.1